# Using line gone

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

So i was building a web api in vs 2022 RC with the ASP.net Core Web Empty template with net 6.

and i noticed that in the program.cs it doesn't show Using system.io etc... It seems to compile and run so im interested in why it is doing this. is this a setting? is this new to the IDE? I cant find it on google maybe i don't know what to search for. Any ideas how to re enable the generating of Using in code it or what is causing it?

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

[image: No using in code picture]

Comment: Ignore the file. it was to test to see if it also worked with system.io it seems to recognize it without adding Using system.io;

Comment: There are now some [implicit global usings](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2021/08/31/implicit-using-statements-in-net-6/) in .NET 6./C# 10.

Comment: If you're used to writing .NET code before .NET 6, then it would be a good idea to [familiarize yourself with the new features](https://rubikscode.net/2021/08/30/net-6-top-6-new-features-in-the-upcoming-net-6-version/) so that you're not surprised and so you don't miss out on taking advantage of the new stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [docs ("Implicit Namespaces")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/6.0/implicit-namespaces):

> .NET 6 introduces implicit namespace support for C# projects. To reduce the amount of `using` directives boilerplate in .NET C# project templates, namespaces are implicitly included by utilizing the `global using` feature introduced in C# 10.
>
> [...]
>
> The default namespaces are included by adding `global using` directives to a generated file in the project's obj directory. The default namespaces are as follows:
>
> | SDK | Default namespaces |
> | --- | --- |
> | Microsoft .NET Sdk | System, System.Collections.Generic, **System.IO**, System.Linq, System.Net.Http, System.Threading, System.Threading.Tasks |

Emphasis mine.